# How to count good nodes in a tree

Tags: java

Given a binary tree root, a node X in the tree is named good if in the path from root to X there are no nodes with a value greater than X.

Return the number of good nodes in the binary tree.

```
   public class TreeNode {
          int val;
         TreeNode left;
      TreeNode right;
      TreeNode() {}
        TreeNode(int val) { this.val = val; }
          TreeNode(int val, TreeNode left, TreeNode right) {
              this.val = val;
             this.left = left;
             this.right = right;
        }
     }
     
    class Solution {
        static int max=0,count=0;
        public int goodNodes(TreeNode root) {
            
            trav(root);
            max=0;
            int s = count;
            count=0;
            return s;
        }
        
        static void trav(TreeNode root)
        {
            if(root==null)
                return;
            if(root.val>=max)
            { max=root.val;
            count++;
            }
              trav(root.left);
              trav(root.right);
        }
    }
```

I am getting  correct answer for following testcases:

```
[3,1,4,3,null,1,5] - 4
[3,3,null,4,2] -3 
[1]-1
```

but for [2,null,4,10,8,null,null,4] im getting 3. I am supposed to get 4.  my max is updated to 10 before it checks 8. how can i solve this with same approach.

Comment: ALL UPPER CASE is considered shouting. Please don't shout.

Comment: i will take care of it next time

Comment: I read your problem wrong the first time. It seems you must have `max` not as global field but as parameter to `trav` so it can come back from a left subtree without having increased `max` for the right subtree.